# Kotlin - overload function with lambda arguments

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I want to have a function that checks whether a property value differs in two given objects. If so, a handler lambda should be executed.

```kotlin
fun <P>onChange(oldObj: P, newObj: P, select: (P) -> Any, handler: (P) -> Unit) {
   val newValues = select(newObj)
   val oldValues = select(oldObj)
   if (oldValues != newValues) { handler(newObj) }
}
```

It works totally fine for the following use case:

```
data class TestObj(
    val foo: String,
    val bar: String? = null
)

val oldObj = TestObj(foo = "foo")
val newObj = TestObj(foo = "foo1", bar = "bar")

onChange(oldObj, newObj, { it.foo }) {
    print("foo did change: ${it.foo}")
}
```

Now I want to be able to check if `bar` has changed. 
If I try to to overload the function like

```kotlin
fun <P>onChange(oldObj: P, newObj: P, select: (P) -> Any?, handler: (P) -> Unit) {
...
}
```

the compiler throws an `Duplicate method name&signature` exception.

How do I overload the function or modify the signature in order to support a `select` lambda that is able to return an optional?

Comment: You won't be able to have one method name with the same arguments in the same order with the only difference being the nullability of the return type (probably, in fact, with the only difference being what kind of function type you're using regardless of how big the difference).  You will need to either use a different method name or pick one version.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Nearly right on the "probably", except different numbers of arguments should allow overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(P) -> Any?` is a subtype of `(P) -> Any`, so if you just have

```
fun <P>onChange(oldObj: P, newObj: P, select: (P) -> Any?, handler: (P) -> Unit)
```

you can pass a `(P) -> Any` there. Of course, with overloading you can have two different implementations, but if behavior is actually different, this seems like a very bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the name. They have the same JVM signature because nullable types don't exist at the byte code level. They are a Kotlin feature enforced at compile time.

Comment: As Louis' comment mentions, the issue would arise even if the difference wasn't nullability, any two single-argument functions would have the same problem.